# Ffmpeg rtmp to hls conversion but how to solve network issue?

Tags: ffmpeg, http-live-streaming, rtmp, hlsl

I'm trying to convert hls stream from rtmp source and its' working fine but the problem is when rtmp server is down or network issue the ffmpeg hls conversion process gets stuck and never comes to work again even if rtmp server is back online.

I've tried

```
-reconnect_at_eof 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5
```

command - it says option is not recognized options by the way I'm using ffmpeg [v4.2.1].

I'm using following ffmpeg commands

```
ffmpeg -i rtmp://localhost/living/test  ^
-max_muxing_queue_size 9999  ^
-async 1 -vf yadif -g 29.97 -r 23 ^
-b:v:0 3150k  -c:v libx264  -filter:v:0 "scale=426:-1" -rc:v vbr_hq -pix_fmt yuv420p -profile:v main -level 4.1 -strict_gop 1 -rc-lookahead 32 -no-scenecut 1 -forced-idr 1  -b:a:0 128k -map 0:v -map 0:a:0 ^
-b:v:1 4200k  -c:v libx264 -filter:v:1 "scale=640:-1" -rc:v vbr_hq -pix_fmt yuv420p -profile:v main -level 4.1 -strict_gop 1 -rc-lookahead 32 -no-scenecut 1 -forced-idr 1   -b:a:1 192k  -map 0:v -map 0:a:0 ^
-b:v:2 5250k  -c:v libx264 -filter:v:2 "scale=1280:-1" -rc:v vbr_hq -pix_fmt yuv420p -profile:v main -level 4.1 -strict_gop 1 -rc-lookahead 32 -no-scenecut 1 -forced-idr 1  -b:a:2 256k -map 0:v -map 0:a:0 ^
 -c:a aac -ar 48000    ^
-f hls ^
-var_stream_map "v:0,a:0  v:1,a:1 v:2,a:2" ^
-master_pl_name  index.m3u8 ^
-t 30000 -hls_time 10 ^
 -hls_init_time 4 -hls_list_size 0 ^
-master_pl_publish_rate 10 ^
-hls_flags delete_segments+discont_start+split_by_time "../live/test/vs%%v/manifest.m3u8" 
pause
```

Comment: Did you use the `-reconnect_*` options as input options? (before `-i`)

Comment: yes i did but it says options not recognized :(

Comment: Show the full log from your command.

Comment: Did you solve it @Baka-MaruLama ?